# Why this query does not work in Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

** I'm bad at English, so sorry.

I'm trying to get records in two date by the query below, but it returns an empty result.

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE 
DATE(dateadd) = '2012-06-03' and DATE(dateadd) = '2012-06-04'
```

Update:

**dateadd** is my datetime column, default is: **0000-00-00 00:00:00**

I use DATE to get date only (not include time). I want to get records in the specific dates, not between.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: exactly how could `dateadd` have two different values at the same time?

Answer (score 7):

You should use `OR` instead of `AND`, how could a date be `2012-06-03` and be `2012-06-04` at the same time?

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE 
DATE(dateadd) = '2012-06-03' OR DATE(dateadd) = '2012-06-04'
```

Comment: One downvoted you. I thnk because `DATE()`, which may be unnecessary.

Comment: @GabrielSantos It is necessary if the column is DATETIME, which is implied by the OP's code.

Comment: I think OP meant `<` and `>` instead of `=`

Comment: Yep, I know, but I think it is only a date field, because of field' name `dateadd`

Comment: @GabrielSantos You never know a column type by the column name, but this is not the point of the question.

Comment: @xdazz In this case, for me, it is implied.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3936f/1 I've put this in a fiddle, in case anyone needs it :)

Comment: i want to get records in multiple dates, not between them.
example: today, a day in last month and a day in last year,... :)